# How to Insert Select Query Results into a Table with a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I want to add the result of a query into another Table that is only for collecting some statistics by stored procedure.

This is what I have achieved: https://sqltest.net/#926688

But the resultset is empty and I do not know why.

```
Table: SurveyData
ID|Variable1|Variable2
 1|        3|        4
 2|        2|        4
 3|        5|        1
```

With a stored procedure I want to count the values of the variable in case they are 4 or 5 and put the result into another table calles Upper_Values

The result should look like this

```
Table: Upper_Values
ID|Var1count|Var2Count
1 |        1|        2
2 | ...
```

The SP I have written for this is:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Put_Values
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Upper_Values(Var1Count, Var2Count)
    Select count(Variable1) as Var1Count, count(Variable2) as Var2Count from surveyData
END
```

Anyone who can help me get this done?

Comment: I am not sure what the question or the issue is here

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: I have adjusted the testsql script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code so it would run.

```
CREATE TABLE sql_server_test_a 
( 
    ID         NVARCHAR(4000), 
    FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR(200), 
    LAST_NAME  NVARCHAR(200) 
); 

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('1', 'Paris', 'Hilton'); 


CREATE TABLE sql_server_test_b
( 
    FIRST NVARCHAR(200),
    LAST NVARCHAR(200)
);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Put_First
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO sql_server_test_b(FIRST, LAST)
    Select FIRST_NAME as FIRST, LAST_NAME as LAST from sql_server_test_a
END
GO

EXEC Put_First;

SELECT * from sql_server_test_b
```

Comment: thanks for your response! Putting this into testsql gives me an empty dataset as my updated query. could you please provide a testsql or similar link where it works.

Comment: I edited it in SSMS. Copy and paste it into there and it will work as expected. I also copied your newer example into SSMS and it worked just fine, so I assume the issue is with testsql.